# PEPPER (SoftBank Robotics): How can I manage ALMemory stored data in Dialog Box within Coregraphe?

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper

I'm programming [Pepper](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/home_pepper.html) to manage ALMemory stored value in dialog topic (as input).

My final goal is to use these inputs (e.g., string) within the Dialog Box in Coregraphe.

Here an example:

```
topic: ~request2()
language: enu

u: (bubble) $myString
```

in which when I say "bubble", the robot returns the content of myString value.

In particular, myString is a "string" input of the block, picked up by

```
myString=ALMemory.getData myStr
```

Is there a way to do this? Could you kindly help me in finding a more effective method to use input parameters in the chat dialog?

Unfortunately, the [ALDialog](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/naoqi/interaction/dialog/aldialog.html?highlight=aldialog) documentation doesn't analyze this aspect.

Sincerely,

GM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it so the dialog activates a custom event that sends your string:

```
u: (trigger) $eventName=parameter
```

After that, simply link the event to the box you want to use or a raise event if you prefer to send it to a web.